Navigation not getting called in useEffect hook
I am trying to call the navigation function to navigate the user from screen A to screen B if API returns the error 404. If the user has not created the profile then API will return the error 404 status code and I will catch it in the catch block then I will check if the status code is 404 if yes then I will navigate the user to create profile screen. So I am getting 404 and console logs are getting printed in the terminal but at first render, it's not navigating the user or the function is not being called in iOS.
useEffect Code:

  useEffect(() => {
    const isUserCreatedProfile = async (loggedInUserInfo) => {
      try {
        await axios
          .get(`${baseUrl}/api/user/profile?email=${loggedInUserInfo?.email}`, {
            headers: apiHeaders,
          })
          .then((res) => {
           // Some logic
            
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            componentErrorHandler("home", "isUserCreatedProfile[axios]", err);
            if (err?.response?.status === 404) {
              console.log("err got", err?.response?.status);
              navigateToCreateProfile(
                loggedInUserInfo["custom:Name"],
                loggedInUserInfo?.email,
              );
              console.log("err got here");
            }
            console.log("err got here 2");
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        componentErrorHandler("home", "isUserCreatedProfile", err);
      }
    };
    if (userInfo?.data) {
      isUserCreatedProfile(userInfo?.data);
    }
  }, [
    chatData?.connected,
    connectUserChat,
    navigateToCreateProfile,
    navigation,
    setUserInfo,
    token?.accessToken,
    userInfo,
    userLocationSave,
  ]);


Navigation Function code:
 const navigateToCreateProfile = useCallback(
    (name, email) => {
      console.log("called navigation");
      navigation.replace("CreateProfile", {
        name,
        email,
      });
    },
    [navigation],
  );


Terminal Logs:

 LOG  home isUserCreatedProfile[axios] [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404]
 LOG  err got 404
 LOG  called navigation
 LOG  err got here
 LOG  err got here 2


I have also tried to remove the function navigateToCreateProfile and add its code inside the catch block only but it still has not worked in iOS.
It only works if I refresh the app again, and then the navigation function gets called.
PS: It works perfectly fine on android.
I am unable to figure out the issue. How can I resolve it?

How can I check my navigation tree? It's a simple function call when API returns 404 status code and in catch I will navigate the user to create a profile. @johnhaup

Post your navigator and the component that’s calling the above.

It works perfectly fine for Android but not for iOS. I am getting navigation in console.log, but any navigation function isn't calling. And, if I re-render the component again somehow then it will call the navigation function.

{"addListener": [Function addListener], "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack], "dispatch": [Function dispatch], "getId": [Function getId], "getParent": [Function getParent], "getState": [Function anonymous], "goBack": [Function anonymous], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], "navigate": [Function anonymous], "pop": [Function anonymous], "popToTop": [Function anonymous], "push": [Function anonymous], "replace": [Function anonymous], "reset": [Function anonymous]
...


This useEffect is the first thing in the component which gets called.

const navigateToCreateProfile = useCallback(
    (name, email) => {
      console.log("called navigation");
      navigation && navigation.replace("CreateProfile", {
        name,
        email,
      });
    },
    [navigation],
  );



No. Still not working. I have also checked navigation and I am getting all functions of navigation in the log but it's not calling it on iOS.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
